# Accessing an XML map element using XSLT

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, element

I am presented with this XML code below. What is the XSLT syntax to access the value of the key "var2"?

```
.
.
<array key = "objects">
    <map>
        <string key "var1">ID</string>
        <string key "var2">Name</string>
        <string key "var3">Weather</string>
    <map>
</array>
.
.
```

I'm no XSLT expert, but I'm familiar in my XSLT work with XML variables and intending to assign the value of "var2" in a variable to display in my translated document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what your current position is in the XML, but to access it for anywhere you could do this...

```
<xsl:variable name="var2" select="//array/map/string[@key='var2']" />
```

Or, if you have multiple `array` objects, and want to target a specific one...

```
<xsl:variable name="var2" select="//array[@key='objects']/map/string[@key='var2']" />
```

(Note, I've assumed your actual XML is valid XML, as it should be `<string key="var2">` and not `<string key "var2">`